# Rails 4.0.2 near "SELECT": syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using this active record query it was working well

```
@deal = Deal.where('city_id = ?', city).where('deal_date <= ? and end_date >= ?', today, today).where('approved = ?', true).includes(:city).last
```

After I updated to Rails 4.0.2 I got this on my browser:

```
near "SELECT": syntax error
```

And the following error on (web brick server)

```
Started GET "/seattle" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 06:36:28 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by DealsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"city_name"=>"seattle"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '00a7213ca6566ff5871c87901f2c37e781366b3b' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."search_name" = 'seattle'
DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one of: deals, cities) that are referenced in a string SQL snippet. For example: 

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")

Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:

    Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)

If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the feature entirely by setting `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. (called from show at /Users/zekarias/Desktop/rails_project/helpon/app/controllers/deals_controller.rb:27)
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT "deals"."id" AS t0_r0, "deals"."name" AS t0_r1, "deals"."regular_price" AS t0_r2, "deals"."initial_discount" AS t0_r3, "deals"."max_discount" AS t0_r4, "deals"."max_threshold" AS t0_r5, "deals"."approved" AS t0_r6, "deals"."deal_date" AS t0_r7, "deals"."blurb_title" AS t0_r8, "deals"."blurb" AS t0_r9, "deals"."tipping_point" AS t0_r10, "deals"."end_date" AS t0_r11, "deals"."company_id" AS t0_r12, "deals"."created_at" AS t0_r13, "deals"."updated_at" AS t0_r14, "deals"."photo_file_name" AS t0_r15, "deals"."photo_content_type" AS t0_r16, "deals"."photo_file_size" AS t0_r17, "deals"."photo_updated_at" AS t0_r18, "deals"."price" AS t0_r19, "deals"."amount_raised" AS t0_r20, "deals"."deal_type" AS t0_r21, "deals"."city_id" AS t0_r22, "deals"."weekend" AS t0_r23, "cities"."id" AS t1_r0, "cities"."name" AS t1_r1, "cities"."search_name" AS t1_r2, "cities"."state_id" AS t1_r3, "cities"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "cities"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "deals" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "deals"."city_id" WHERE (city_id = SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."search_name" = 'seattle') AND (deal_date <= '2014-02-01' and end_date >= '2014-02-01') AND (approved = 't') ORDER BY "deals"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
SQLite3::SQLException: near "SELECT": syntax error: SELECT  "deals"."id" AS t0_r0, "deals"."name" AS t0_r1, "deals"."regular_price" AS t0_r2, "deals"."initial_discount" AS t0_r3, "deals"."max_discount" AS t0_r4, "deals"."max_threshold" AS t0_r5, "deals"."approved" AS t0_r6, "deals"."deal_date" AS t0_r7, "deals"."blurb_title" AS t0_r8, "deals"."blurb" AS t0_r9, "deals"."tipping_point" AS t0_r10, "deals"."end_date" AS t0_r11, "deals"."company_id" AS t0_r12, "deals"."created_at" AS t0_r13, "deals"."updated_at" AS t0_r14, "deals"."photo_file_name" AS t0_r15, "deals"."photo_content_type" AS t0_r16, "deals"."photo_file_size" AS t0_r17, "deals"."photo_updated_at" AS t0_r18, "deals"."price" AS t0_r19, "deals"."amount_raised" AS t0_r20, "deals"."deal_type" AS t0_r21, "deals"."city_id" AS t0_r22, "deals"."weekend" AS t0_r23, "cities"."id" AS t1_r0, "cities"."name" AS t1_r1, "cities"."search_name" AS t1_r2, "cities"."state_id" AS t1_r3, "cities"."created_at" AS t1_r4, "cities"."updated_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "deals" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "deals"."city_id" WHERE (city_id = SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."search_name" = 'seattle') AND (deal_date <= '2014-02-01' and end_date >= '2014-02-01') AND (approved = 't')  ORDER BY "deals"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Completed 500  in 123ms

SQLite3::SQLException - near "SELECT": syntax error:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying you need to add `.references(:city)` in your query as:

```
@deal = Deal.where(
                'city_id = ?', city
             ).where(
                'deal_date <= ? and end_date >= ?', today, today
             ).where(
                'approved = ?', true
             ).includes(:city).references(:city).last
```

The `references(:city)` is only required if "string syntax" is used i.e.

```
where('city_id = ?', city)
```

An alternative to this is using the hash syntax:

```
where(city: { city_id: city_id })
```

in which case Rails 4 does not require `references(:city)`.

When defining a join query it is recommended to always include the table name or it's alias when referencing the a column.  This ensures that you don't run in to "Ambiguous Column Name" error.  An example of this would be:

```
Deal.includes(:city).where('cities.city_id = ?', city_id)
```

Note the `where('cities.city_id = ?', city_id)` is specifically saying where `city_id` of `cities` table whereas if you use `where('city_id = ?', city_id)` then the query processor wouldn't know which table's `city_id` column to use.

With both the fixes applied, your final query would be:

```
@deal = Deal.where(
                    'cities.city_id = ?', city
                 ).where(
                    'deals.deal_date <= ? and deals.end_date >= ?', today, today
                 ).where(
                    'deals.approved = ?', true
                 ).includes(:city).references(:city).last
```

Comment: I had been tried the same code before I posted it. I just got the same old story: 'SQLite3::SQLException - near "SELECT": syntax error:'